# Why are my dir-locals always malformed

Tags: directory-local-variables, project

I was reading about dir-locals and wanted to set up per project settings. However whatever I try results in a malformed function. Why is this ?

```
.dir-locals.el:4:1:Warning: ‘(php-mode (php-executable . /usr/bin/php))’ is a
malformed function
```

So I tried this as the most basic example I could think of, and even this raises an error.

```
((php-mode
  (php-executable . /usr/bin/php)))
```

So what am i doing wrong? I edit the file and then compile it to check things are working and checked multiple examples online and they all seem to use this format.

From the answers below this is an example I wanted to make work, the above was just a simpler test.

`((nil . 
      ((pony-settings (make-pony-project
                       :python "/docker:root@app_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python"
                       :pythonpath "/app"
                       :settings "local_settings_file"
                       :appsdir "/app")
                      ))))`

This is where my issues stemmed from, I can switch to a file and I hit an error which is what made me try and compile the code so I could test quickly.

```
eval: Invalid function: (make-pony-project :python "/docker:root@app_django_1:/usr/local/bin/python" :pythonpath "/app" :settings "local_settings_file" :appsdir "/app")
```

Perhaps this should be another question now, but in away this is still an issue I am getting an error but cant modify and apply changes quickly to see if its valid. Anyone have any idea on the above error ?

Comment: I don't have answer for your question. But if you use `M-x add-dir-local-variable` then you don't need to worry about the format. Besides, I guess `php-executable` requires string type as its value, so you should use `"/usr/bin/php"` instead.

Comment: funny you should say that the above was generated from add-dir-local-variable then I compiled it to check it was valid which is when i hit the issue, quoting results in the same error.

Comment: Oops, you can't byte compile `.dir-locals.el` since it is not valid Emacs Lisp code.

Comment: Is there a way to execute it to test that the file is valid, as thats the main thing I was trying to do just check my code was valid.

Comment: Test it by opening a file under the directory it’s in in php-mode, and do M-: php-executable, after having changed the path to be a string as xuchunyang said.

Comment: @Oly I always think it is already valid if it is created via `M-x add-dir-local-variable`. Besides even if it is not, you should notice something is incorrect in time.

Comment: I will try that I was hoping for a better way, its fine in this simple example but when dir-locals has 100 odd lines configuring various settings then it would be nice to know the file is valid, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: You should read the right sources. `M-x (info "(emacs) Directory Variables")` and `M-x (info "(elisp) Directory Local Variables")`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't get directory local variables to work - Debugger encountered Lisp error](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/38539/cant-get-directory-local-variables-to-work-debugger-encountered-lisp-error)

Comment: Oly: As others have pointed out, that value needs to be a string: `"/usr/bin/php"`. You need to manually type the quotes because `add-dir-local-variable` has no idea what *type* of value is required/valid for any given variable, so string values need to be made explicit. (Despite looking like a file path, the value you'd actually entered was a symbol rather than a string.)

Comment: Yes that makes sense that it should be quoted the add-dir-local-variable made it in that format, I have appended the question with another example Which is what made me try a simpler php test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the original question (repeating my comment):

As others have pointed out, that value needs to be a string: `"/usr/bin/php"`. You need to manually type the quotes because `add-dir-local-variable` has no idea what type of value is required/valid for any given variable, so string values need to be made explicit. (Despite looking like a file path, the value you'd actually entered was a symbol rather than a string.)

---

For the revised/new question:

```
((nil . ((pony-settings (make-pony-project ...
```

is the same as:

```
((nil . ((pony-settings . ((make-pony-project ...
```

So you're setting `pony-settings` to `((make-pony-project ...))`

And it sounds like that form is then evaluated like so:

```
((make-pony-project ...))
```

Hence:

```
eval: Invalid function: (make-pony-project ...)
```

Because while `make-pony-project` may be the name of a function, the form `(make-pony-project ...)` is not the name of a function.

So in summary, I suspect you're missing a dot.  Try:

```
((nil . ((pony-settings . (make-pony-project ...
```

See also the "Notation" heading at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DirectoryVariables#toc1

Comment: Thats is a great answer, but i still see the same invalid function, the code i was using was directly from the pony docs here https://github.com/davidmiller/pony-mode, possible they are wrong I guess will try a few more things in case i am doing something wrong still

Comment: Thank you pointed me in the correct direction, the answer seems to be the first dot does should not be there the second should, found another page with docs with the correct info here http://www.deadpansincerity.com/docs/pony/configuration.html if you want to update i will accept ass a working solution :)

Comment: The structure of the form shown in that linked page is `equal` to the one in my answer. I suspect that you have again been tripped up by dotted pair notation (or lack thereof), and did not test with the correct dots and parentheses for the notation you were using.

Comment: i.e. `((nil (pony-settings ...)))` and `((nil . ((pony-settings ...))))` are the same. It's valuable to get familiar with those notation differences/equivalences. (Again, see that Emacs Wiki link for more information.)

Comment: FWIW I feel that dotted-pair notation makes the `.dir-locals.el` format far more readable (bearing in mind that it's generally representing *lists* of var/value pairs), and that it's unfortunate that `add-dir-local-variable` does not generate that format. Personally I would recommend writing the file manually using dotted-pair notation.

Comment: your correct I tried again must have missed a bracket or something, thanks again accepted your answer.